# Volatile properties in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, var, volatile

How does one mark a var in Kotlin volatile?

`volatile public var tmpEndedAt: Long? = null`

gives me the error:

> "unresolved reference: volatile"

Comment: Can you show us more code? The web IDE let's me compile your code just fine: http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/117433846956340982849-2093063043/117433846956340982849-1340790681

Comment: Possible issues with your project: 1) it may be a JS-taregeted project 2) kotlin standard library may not be attached

Comment: Your line of code seems to be correct. In Kotlin `volatile` is not a keyword but an annotation declared in `kotlin-stdlib`. So just make sure to have it in classpath.

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out, posted the answer below.

Comment: Correct is `@Volatile` annotation.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I decided to give Kotlin a shot by just using the "convert java to kotlin" function in IntelliJ. Apparently that set things up wrong.

I tried doing the same thing, but after applying the Kotlin Gradle plugin and placing the file in `src/kotlin` and it all worked. Thanks for the help anyway guys.

The code would be:

```
@Volatile var tmpEndedAt: Long? = null
```

Comment: I have encountered this problem before. Here's an issue, I just created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7986

Comment: Will it be compiled even without `kapt`? I'm asking because I have a lot of old Java classes with many lombok annotations so I can't use `kapt` with that or it breaks everything.

Answer (score 17):

In Kotlin in order to force changes in a variable to be immediately visible to other threads, we can use the annotation `@Volatile`.
If a variable is not shared between multiple threads, you don't need to use `volatile` keyword with that variable.

I.e. when you apply `volatile` to a field of a class, it instructs the CPU to always read it from the *RAM* and not from the *CPU* cache. It also prevents instructions reordering; it acts as a memory barrier.

Check [Volatile in O’Reilly's Kotlin Quick Start Guide](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/kotlin-quick-start/9781789344189/72784c56-a356-4604-8545-aaaddf7da832.xhtml) for more information.

Answer (score 15):

According to the Kotlin documentation [Kotlin-@Volatile](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-volatile/index.html)

> Marks the JVM backing field of the annotated property as volatile, meaning that writes to this field are immediately made visible to other threads.

So, in Kotlin you can mark the property as `volatile` with `@Volatile` annotation.

**e.g.**

```
@Volatile var tmpEndedAt: Long? = null
```